# Do I understand levels of z-index correctly?

Tags: css, z-index, layer

Can you please help me clarify? If we have some multi-level structure, f.e.

```
.div-1
  .div-2
  .div-2
    .div-3
```

It's impossible to hide `.div-3` behind `.div-1` using `z-index` in anyway? We can manipulate layers on same level of DOM? Is it correct statement?

Then how do we make layouts where we want an item of `.div-3` hide behind main app layer `.div-1`? Let's say we have a closing button of `.div-3` that we want to roll out of (from beneath) `.div-1`?

If I have explained poorly, I will clarify.

Comment: Why would you want anything behind the main app layer? Why have anything that is not visible?

Comment: I'm afraid this question is a bit too abstract. If you can create a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) of code that demonstrates what you want to have happen, we might be able to help you understand why it's not working, and perhaps methods for making it work.

Comment: You can read about the painting order in the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-position-3/#painting-order).

Comment: in my particular case i have made(don't ask what weed i smoked, but that's my concept and i want to make it exactly that way) a todo list where main div is
    .todo
and inside it there are 
    .todo__rowItem
that has different elements and among them there is a .close-div button - a simple element that rolls out from behind of .todo(main layer) everytime a row element is being edited. And that happens on every row element independently. You can see a screen shot of that idea here
    https://i.paste.pics/37cb5c73b19995a410c72fcb802a6bef.png